# Why must some 'dangerous items' be in check-in baggage?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation

What is the rationale behind forcing passengers to check in dangerous items?

What makes liquids and gels more dangerous in the cabin? Why would a lithium ion battery be less dangerous as check-in luggage? Wouldn't that even be more dangerous when you put lots of batteries in the cabin, since one could catch fire and spread to all other batteries where passengers are?

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/651/)

Answer (score 32):

Generally, "dangerous" things that might be used as weapons are required to be kept out of the cabin. For instance, you can have firearms in checked baggage, but not carried in the cabin.

Given what's been learned about terrorist planning, there were plots to bring liquids on board an aircraft that could be combined to form an explosive. To counter that threat, the amounts & types of liquids that can be brought on board have been limited. Since the liquids in isolation are safe, they're allowed in normal quantities in checked luggage.

In the case of Lithium Ion batteries, the concern is less their use as a weapon, and more about a defective battery catching fire. If this were to happen in a cargo hold, the fire would cause other things to start burning as well before the cargo smoke detectors alert the crew to what's going on. So the priority is to keep lithium ion batteries out of the cargo hold. They're allowed in the cabin (with some restrictions) since you're pretty likely to notice your cell phone getting hot & smoking if it's in your pocket, and with that sort of early notice, the fire can be dealt with before it's caught large volumes of material on fire as well.

At least that's the theory. I don't know how many times it's been put to the test. In at least two cases (the Samsung Note 7 phone, and hover boards), devices which are considered to be at high risk of catching fire are simply kept off the aircraft altogether.

Comment: Can we get a citation on the liquid aspect? That seems pretty unbelievable that liquids mixed by a person are a threat, and liquids mixed by some Macguyvered mechanism would not be a threat.

Comment: @Scott You have more faith in the TSA's rationality than I have. https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2014/01/tsa-business-security-theater-not-security/357599/ https://www.schneier.com/essays/archives/2009/11/beyond_security_thea.html

Comment: There's been a recent case of some dude biting into an iPhone battery and making quite a mess on the Internet, if I remember correctly. Hopefully terrorists on airplanes won't learn that trick.

Comment: @Scott "_liquids mixed by some Macguyvered mechanism would not be a threat_" Presumably the idea is that scanning of hold-baggage would spot anything more suspicious than completely separate containers.

Comment: @scott in the TSA's own words:  https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2008/02/04/more-liquid-rules-why-we-do-things-we-do-commenting-disabled (which doesn't really answer the question, though); a better explanation at https://science.howstuffworks.com/liquid-explosives.htm describes several combinations of relatively safe chemicals that can be mixed into an explosive.  Fox News even describes how Tang drink mix and the hydrogen peroxide from your medicine cabinet can make a bomb. http://www.foxnews.com/story/2008/05/17/tang-bomb-liquid-explosives-are-new-weapon-choice.html

Comment: @Scott There are lots of liquids that, if mixed, are explosive or incendiary. A basic chemistry class should resolve any disbelief of that. As for the MacGyvered mechanism in hold baggage, hold baggage is x-ray screened and (at least in the U.S.) also tested for explosives, so the idea is that they'd catch that in screening and not let the bag on the plane. For carry-on baggage, someone could take their bag into a lav (or a first class suite, etc.) and combine the chemicals manually, so there would be no MacGyvered mechanism for security to detect.

Comment: The term for the liquid mixable explosives is [binary explosives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_explosive).

Comment: I believe there was a letter to the TSA signed by quite a few Nobel laureates in chemistry that the idea of a liquid binary explosive being a danger to a plane was not based on any known science. In other words, Security Theater.

Comment: The fire danger is even more important for lithium-metal batteries (such as the little coin-shaped ones in computer motherboards) than for lithium-ion and lithium-polymer batteries, since burning lithium-metal batteries are essentially _impossible_ to extinguish; the only thing that can be done is to isolate it from other combustibles before it ignites anything else and keep it isolated until it burns itself out, which is much easier to do in the passenger cabin than in the cargo hold.  This is the reason lithium-metal batteries are completely banned from any sort of air transport...

Comment: ... _except_ for those installed in personal electronic devices (laptops, for instance) plus up to one spare battery per device, all of which _must_ be in carryon rather than checked baggage.

Answer (score 13):

> Why is the rationale of forcing passengers to check-in dangerous items?

To stop people using them as weapons to hijack the plane.

> What makes liquids and gels more dangerous in the cabin?

There was a terrorist plot in which suicide bombers would blow up planes using [liquid explosives disguised as soft drinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_transatlantic_aircraft_plot). Of course, somebody could try to put such a bomb in checked luggage but that would require some sort of timer and detonator, which would likely be spotted when the luggage is X-rayed. So the specific concern is that a bomb could be assembled and detonated in the cabin using only innocent-looking liquids and other items.

> Why would a li-ion battery be less dangerous as check-in luggage? Wouldn't that even be more dangerous when you put lots of batteries in the cabin, since one could catch fire and spread to all other batteries where passengers are?

Lithium batteries are *more* dangerous in check-in luggage.

How would the fire spread between batteries in the passenger compartment, unless the whole cabin is on fire? Your laptop isn't suddenly going to start burning just because my cell phone has caught fire in the seat next to you.

If a battery fire starts in the cabin, somebody will notice *before* it sets much else on fire. They can then put the fire out. The standard technique, I believe, is to drop it in a bucket of water, which removes all the heat from the system, as well as starving it of oxygen. Everybody lives to tell the tale.

In contrast, if a battery fire starts in the cargo hold, it's in an area that's densely packed with flammable things such as clothing. That means that, by the time the fire is detected, it is probably quite big. Further, the only way to fight such a fire is with a general fire suppression system that tries to starve the entire hold of oxygen. That doesn't remove the heat so, even if it puts the fire out, it's possible that the still overheated battery will reignite the fire. This is an extremely dangerous situation that could well kill everybody.

Comment: I don't believe the standard technique for a battery fire is to drop it in a bucket of water. Do they have buckets big enough for a laptop at all? They'll use a class D-rated fire suppression agent, which would work both on a lithium primary and a lithium-ion fire.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Probably not for a laptop. But for phones, I think that's the procedure.

Comment: Notice that this approach might work for some types of lithium based batteries, but not all. And it's not always possible to know what type of battery you have at hand.

Comment: @QuoraFeans -- Li-Ions *always* are suppressed using water to quench the runaway reaction.  Class D agents can be actively harmful due to the fact that a burning Li-Ion battery has oxygenated fuels and decomposing cathode oxide (producing oxygen) in it already, so it doesn't need all that much air to burn or propagate the runaway to adjacent cells.

Comment: does water even work for Li-ion batteries (in terms of the battery not burning anymore), or does it work solely to contain the damage?

Comment: @JohnDvorak It's got a huge specific heat capacity so it stops the thermal runaway, as well as absorbing the damage.

Comment: Regarding lithium-based batteries, [Why is there so much fear surrounding LiPo batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/230155/5830) on [electronics.se] may be of interest.

Comment: Wait, they drop _lithium_ batteries in _water_? [That just sounds like a bad idea.](https://youtu.be/vRKK6pliejs?t=32s)

Comment: @reirab if you don't drop it in water, [it does this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EseOhC8n7ro). I know which I prefer! The water absorbs the heat and contains the reaction. The resulting lithium hydroxide solution is presumably rather dilute so not very dangerous.

Comment: @reirab So you have a choice between "releases toxic fumes and stays nicely contained in a water bucket" or "releases toxic fumes and also catches everything else on fire". Pick one

Comment: @immibis It was more of the "alkaili metals react violently with water" part that was my primary concern than the release of toxic fumes. Accidentally combining lithium and water is how meth manufacturers who failed chemistry regularly blow themselves up. Perhaps a large enough bucket of water would be sufficient to contain the resulting explosion from the quantity of lithium in a small battery, though.

Comment: @reirab I think containing the energy is the point (water has an unusually large ability to absorb heat), along with the fact that you have an alkali metal fire either way.

Comment: @reirab, lithium doesn't explode when mixed with water.  Lithium produces hydrogen and heat when mixed with water, and it's the hot hydrogen that explodes.  Drop your lithium in enough water, and you get cold hydrogen that never builds up to explosive levels.